# Rails 3 - RefineryCMS Edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator, refinerycms

I am using refinery cms edge version from github for my personal blog.  I have installed the blog plugin but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the generators to work. It says i should have a generator called `refinerycms_blogs` but I get an error saying this generator is not installed when I try to use it.

Could anyone give me some advice on how these generators should work?

Cheers

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Use this generator instead:

```
rails g refinery:blog
```

The generator name was updated for the edge version. This is documented in the readme, but for that branch: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog/tree/rails-3-1#readme

Cheers,
Phil